# WP_Query : Search and Filter Using custom field AND/OR custom taxonomy

Tags: wp-query

I've not been able to find my way using the existing answers; hence decided to post a new question anyway. What I want to achieve has probably been done 20,000 times; but I might just be an idiot. Anyway -

What I have:
1. Custom Post Type: 'job'
2. Each 'job' has: custom_filed_1: location , custom_field_2: company
3. It also has: custom_taxonomy_1: skills, custom_taxonomy_2: disciplines

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to write WP_QUERY that will help me retrieve posts that have: custom_field_1 AND custom_taxonomy_1 AND custom_taxonomy_2.

Like searching for jobs available in "New York" AND Skills "PHP + WordPress" AND available for "Computer Science Engineers".

My main confusion is how do I have 'AND' / 'OR' relationship between 'meta_query' and 'tax_query' arguments of WP_Query.

Would really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Here's my sample code:

```
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => array('job'),
    'post_status' => array('publish'),
    'posts_per_page' => '5',

     'meta_query' => array(
          'relation' => 'AND',
           array(
               'key' => 'location',
               'value' => $search_location, 
               'compare' => 'LIKE',
               ),
          array(
               'key' => 'company',
               'value' => $search_company, 
               'compare' => 'LIKE',
               ),     
        ),
     'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
         array(
          'taxonomy' => 'skills',
          'field'    => 'slug', 
          'terms'    => $search_skills,
          'operator' => 'IN'
         ),
        array(
                 'taxonomy' => 'disciplines',
          'field'    => 'slug', 
          'terms'    => $search_disciplines,
          'operator' => 'IN'
),
    );
```

Comment: Sorry for the bump; but can someone please push me in the right direction?

Answer (score -1):

Maby this example can help:

```
<?php

global $wp_query; // get the global object

$thesearch = get_search_query(); // get the string searched

// merge them with one or several meta_queries to meet your demand
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, array( 
   'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'field_to_seach',
        'value' => $thesearch,
        'compare' => 'IN'
    )
)
    ));
query_posts( $args ); // alter the main query to include your custom parameters

?>
```

**UPDATE:**

This is realy bad practice but in the some custom works you can use it in some realy rare occasion.

Alos read this note:

> Note: This function will completely override the main query and isn’t
>   intended for use by plugins or themes. Its overly-simplistic approach
>   to modifying the main query can be problematic and should be avoided
>   wherever possible. In most cases, there are better, more performant
>   options for modifying the main query such as via the ‘pre_get_posts’
>   action within WP_Query.
>
> This must not be used within the WordPress Loop.

[More about it here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/)

Comment: Note that using `query_posts()` is not considered best practice anymore, check e.g. the harsh warnings in the [Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/).

Comment: I know that but in some cases can be used. I not like it but can be helpful.